# Looking for peers peercount=0 forever; what should I do?

Tags: go-ethereum

[image]

geth --goerli --datadir=./ethdata --syncmode "fast" --cache 4096 --http --http.addr 192.168.1.36 --http.port 19000 --http.api eth,net,web3     console

Comment: 1) Make sure you do not have firewall issues and geth gets a public IP address 2) wait longer

Comment: Like @MikkoOhtamaa said, make sure you don't have firewall which is blocking geth ports. Then check if your geth version is up to date with the latest geth version, you can check that at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases . Also make sure once you are starting geth there are no errors in the logs. After geth restart, it should take you not more than hour to connect to peers.